# How do I change the colour of selected piece of image using tap gesture recognizer on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a image of human face that is divided into 10 different parts (1 to 10). When I select any parts of the image, I want that part in a different colour. How is it possible using tap gesture recognizer..?

[image: Human face image that i am using my app]

Comment: It the human face one big image, or several smaller ones?

Comment: Yes, human face is a one big image..and 1 to 10 are smaller parts of it.

Comment: Well, that makes it quite hard... You have to make transparent views with the approximate size and location of the part of the face, then you can assign to each view (1 to 10) a tapgesturerecognizer.

Comment: It is not possible for one big image. YOu need to make the face with images from 1 to 10 and then you can able to do it

Comment: But there is one hard way to do it. YOu need to know the positions of the image parts,so let's say if you tap anywhere in between (10,20) to (20,20) you recognise it as forehead and mask that area with different color

Comment: @Mr.T Ok thanks for guidance but how to make a one big image from 10 different shapes images...?

Comment: do you have different shape images ready? are those just images or custom uiviews? if they are images , are they square images or are they pngs ?

Comment: Yes i have different shape of pngs and those are just images not a custom uiviews

Comment: y dont you create a custom view by placing all the images in one view ?

Comment: try using imageviews first, and see if you can get it as close as you need.

Comment: I am new to objective c so i dont know how to make custom view by placing all the images in one view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89171/discussion-between-mohit-and-mr-t).

Answer (score 0):

You can add Single Tap Gesture Recognizer, just like this.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singletapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTapGesture:)];

[self.testView addGestureRecognizer:singletapGestureRecognizer];
```

}

Now in the method, give color to the image that you want.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response...but i have a one question...in my case one big image have a 10 different parts and each part divided by white boundary. if i tap on number 1 part then i want change the colour of only part that covered by number 1 and remaining parts as it is.

Comment: I currently don't have mac. You can also set the tags of all the images and inside the singleTapGestureRecognizer method, get the tag and change the color for selected state.

Comment: but i only have one big image..!!